# How can I embed 2 tableau dashboards in 1 website?

Tags: javascript

Currently, based on JavaScript, I have embedded one tableau dashboard in a website, code is shown below. Now, I want to embed 2 dashboard in a same website (this second dashboard is from another tableau publish web link like the one I am using), how could I do it? Meanwhile, I need to create something like 'switch' button to allow me switch to different dashboard contents on click. Can anyone please help me with this?

**Current code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Basic Embed</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initViz() {
            var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
                url = "https://us-east-1.online.tableau.com/t/zuar/views/Regional/GlobalTemperatures",
                options = {
                    hideTabs: true,
                    onFirstInteractive: function () {
                        console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                    }
                };

            var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
            // Create a viz object and embed it in the container div.
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initViz();">
    <div id="vizContainer" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways how to implement that - which approach would you prefer and what did you try so far?

Comment: what's a "tableau dashboard"?

Comment: @Liam Another dashboard added to the millions out there already -> https://www.tableau.com/

Comment: @iLuvLogix What kind of ways? I could find lots of ways of putting in 1 dashboard only, but hasn't seen any ways of putting multiple dashboards in the same website. Any specific example that I could mimic or tutorial to that?

Comment: @Fred See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple js-toggle func and toggle between the dashboards or whatever content you want to have. Just replace the text-content of the respective divs with the viz-containers of your dashboards..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"> 
</script>


<script>
function toggle() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById("dashboard1");
  var x2 = document.getElementById("dashboard2");
  var bl = document.getElementById("button1");

  if (x1.style.display === "none") {
    x1.style.display = "block";
    x2.style.display = "none";
    bl.firstChild.data = "To Data B";
  } else {
    x1.style.display = "none";
    x2.style.display = "block";
    bl.firstChild.data = "To Data A";
  }
}

function initialize() {


var containerDiv1 = document.getElementById("dashboard1"),
            url1 = "https://public.tableau.com/views/liveintegration1/Dashboard1",
            options1 = {
                hideTabs: true,
                onFirstInteractive: function () {
                    console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                }
            };

        var viz1 = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv1, url1, options1);
        // Create a viz object and embed it in the container div.


var containerDiv2 = document.getElementById("dashboard2"),
            url2 ="https://public.tableau.com/views/LearnEmbeddedAnalytics/SalesOverviewDashboard",
            options2 = {
                hideTabs: true,
                onFirstInteractive: function () {
                    console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                }
            };

        var viz2 = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv2, url2, options2);
}

</script>

<style>
#dashboard1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width:800px; 
  height:700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#dashboard2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width:800px; 
  height:700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<button id="button1" onclick="toggle()">To Data B</button>

<div id="dashboard1" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>

<div id="dashboard2" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

When inspecting the page you can now see the iframe being imported to the empty div:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Will attempt and ask later!

Comment: np - you are welcome ;) Keep in mind that you need to instantiate both tableau's in your script and call them in your _onload_ declaration (you could use a single wrapper func and instantiate them in there..)

Comment: Just realize that is an issue: there are 2 dashboard from different web link, how could I onload them in your code? I am not sure how to do that. I can give you another link, could you add both of them in your code? Much appreciated!

Comment: You can find the first link in the original code; Another link: https://public.tableau.com/views/LearnEmbeddedAnalytics/SalesOverviewDashboard

Comment: How kind! Thanks again! I tried but it alert me with 'myFunction is not defined
'. It seems that I made some mistakes and don't really know how to adapt it to what I need.

Comment: In my last edit I renamed the function _myFunction()_ to _toggle()_ ;)

Comment: Have tried your code? It seems not working properly to display the tableau I meant to......

Comment: The second page can be viewed as designed, however, the first page appears to be blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223712/discussion-between-iluvlogix-and-fred).

Comment: Hope I didn't spoil your lovely evening......However, there is a big issue in the updated code: every time I first launch the website, I can always see both first and second dashboards appear on the first page, where should only have the first dashboard. And once I click the toggle button twice and come back to the same page, the second dashboard will disappear. Why is this happening and how to make the second dashboard never appear on the first dashboard's page even from the very beginning? It will be wonderful if you have some spare time help me out. Cheers

Comment: I tried to add display:none as the first version of your answer suggest, although this can remove the second dashboard in the first page, but this will make the second dashboard in the second page also disappear. Any solution to make them display as designed?